# Accessing a django function/module in iOS

Tags: ios, django

Here is what I am trying to do:

I'm implementing a search function in python that would be used in this sort of fashion:

```
search(query)
```

I'm using a Django + TastyPie JSON api to link a PostgreSQL db to an iOS app. It's been easy (so far) to perform CRUD operations on my tables, but now I want to do something decidedly more complex.

What would be the best way to implement this? I want instant search, which I could do in-browser with backbone or the like. Something like google instant search.

I thought that I could, potentially, connect the function to a view at http://search.example.com/query, which would return some JSON aligned with the query 'query'. The problem is, doing this via http seems inefficient:

```
http://search.example.com/q
http://search.example.com/qu
http://search.example.com/que
http://search.example.com/quer
http://search.example.com/query
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: if you can think of an easier method to get your idevice to talk to a remote server than an http request, feel free to astound the world with it.

Comment: Yeah. I guess there's a typo. My mistake. Then, does my question make sense?